# How i can import to python from file.txt in this script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cat

i have this code but i want to import from file.txt addresses.
How to modify? i tried with "cat" 
"python cashconverter.py  output.txt"
but is not working. Thanks

```
from cashaddress import convert

import sys
if len(sys.argv) != 2 :
    print("usage : bhcconvert <cashAddrss>")
else :
    addrss = sys.argv[1]
    addrss = addrss.replace('bitcoincash:' , '')
    if convert.is_valid('bitcoincash:' + addrss) :
        print( convert.to_legacy_address('bitcoincash:' + addrss))
    else :
        sys.stderr.write('Invalid address\n')
```

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to put/get in your .txt ? the code ? or the addresses ? This question seems offtopic and related to #bash and #shell more than #python if you want to move this file contents

Comment: i need to import the address

Comment: If you want to set some text from your `python` script to a `.txt` you may want something like : 
`open('file.txt', 'w').write(addrss)`
Here's a [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp). But that's pretty basic python, you could have searched a bit more on google before asking there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this two ways, ( presuming you a `file.txt` with one address in each line )

1.Using `python`,

```
$ cat bhcconvert.py # assuming `bhcconvert.py` is the name of your script
from cashaddress import convert
import sys

def check():
  with open('file.txt') as f:
    for addrss in f:
      if addrss.strip():
        addrss = addrss.strip().replace('bitcoincash:' , '')
        if convert.is_valid('bitcoincash:' + addrss) :
          print( convert.to_legacy_address('bitcoincash:' + addrss))
        else :
          sys.stderr.write('Invalid address\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    check()
```

2.using `shell`,

```
while read -r address; do python bhcconvert.py "$address";done <file.txt
```